# Group by foreign key

Tags: laravel

Tabla alliances

```
Schema::create('alliances', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('imgAlliances')->nullable();
    $table->string('nameAlliances')->nullable();
    $table->integer('amountAlliances')->nullable();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_type_alliances')->nullable();
    $table->foreign('id_type_alliances')->references('id')->on('type_alliances');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Tabla type_alliances

```
Schema::create('type_alliances', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('nameType_en')->nullable();
    $table->string('nameType_es')->nullable();
    $table->string('nameType_pt')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Modelo

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\typeAlliance;

class alliance extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function type()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(typeAlliance::class , 'id_type_alliances');
    }
}
```

Controlador

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\alliance;

class AllianceIndex extends Component
{
    public function render()
    {

        $alliances = alliance::all()->groupby('id_type_alliances');

        return view('livewire.alliance-index', compact('alliances'))->extends('layouts.index');

    }
}
```

Vista

```
@foreach ($alliances as $id_type_alliances => $items)
    <h4>Alianza {{ $id_type_alliances }}</h4>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <ul class="list-group">
            @foreach ($items as $item)
                <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    {{ $item->nameAlliances }}
                    <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill"> {{ $item->id }}</span>
                </li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </ul>
@endforeach
```

Todo me funciona bien, lo que pasa es que el **id_type_alliances** es una llave foranea y quiero mostrar el nombre mas bien del id

intente colocando **id_type_alliances->type->name** y no me funciona.

al colocar dentro segundo foreach **$item->type->name** si me trae el nombre de la relación

no se que cambiar para que me quede funcionar ya que no e podido resolver esto

Gracia ante mano

Comment: Buen día, puedes intentar agregando protected $with = ['type']; en tu modelo, justo abajo de $guarded y también puedes agregar la version de laravel que estas usando?

Comment: Buenos dias... estoy utilizando laravel 8 no entiendo a que te refieres a $with

Comment: podria ser algo asi `$alliances = alliance::with('type')->get()->groupby('nameType_es');`

Comment: lo que te dice @HeytalePazguato sobre `protected $with = ['type'];` es que llamara automaticamente la relacion entre alliances y type_alliances ya que existe el metodo type() en tu modelo.